# Issue with CoreTelphony framework

Tags: ios8.3, core-telephony

Prior to iOS8.3 we were able to get the caller number using "CTCallCopyAddress". In iOS8.3 and above the address received using "CTCallCopyAddress" is 0x0, so unable to get the Caller Number. Apple has restricted the access to caller number in iOS8.3 and above ? Please let me know if there is any other alternate method for getting the Caller Number.

Comment: Did you ever find out if there is an alternative to CTCallCopyAddress for iOS 9?

Comment: No there is no alternative way to CTCallCopyAddress in iOS9.